# using List<customObject> as dictionary key c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a dictionary the key for which is a list which is as  follows

```
var dict = new Dictionary<List<MyKey>, Emp>(new MyCustomComparer());
```

I am having trouble implementing the List comparer. Even though the value exists the containskey  always returns false. This is code I have written

Program.cs

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<List<MyKey>, Emp>(new MyCustomComparer());

        var key1 = new List<MyKey>
                       {
                           {new MyKey{ Name = "string1"}}
                       };

        dict.Add(key1, new Emp());
        var key2 = new List<MyKey>
                       {
                           {new MyKey{ Name = "string1"}}
                       };


        if (!dict.ContainsKey(key2))
        {
            dict.Add(key2, new Emp());
        }
```

Key class

```
public class MyKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public class Emp
{
}
```

Comparer class

```
public class MyCustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<MyKey>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<MyKey> x, List<MyKey> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<MyKey> obj)
    {
        return string.Join(",", obj.Select(s => s.Name)).GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

regards

Comment: You have no `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementations in your `MyKey` class so the comparisons in `SequenceEqual` are going to compare references, not the values of the `Name` property.

Comment: Your `GetHashCode()` is also a problem, it is getting the hash code of the `IEnumerable<string>` that is returned. But your bigger problem is if you change one of the lists while it is performing the roll as a key it will break the dictionary. Dictionary can not handle objects mutating while they perform the roll of key.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: It would be about having `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in key type, but yeah, that is what it is.

Comment: In addition to @ScottChamberlain, you should at least use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`. Having mutable structures as a dictionary key can bite you... Second, the  `GetHashCode` for `MyCustomComparer` is returning the hash code of `IEnumerable<T>`, not from the Name properties. I think you forgot to join the strings?

Comment: Also, even if you use an immutable list, and implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on `MyKey` to depend on `MyKey.Name`, you still have the issue that `MyKey.Name` is mutable - if the value of that property changes in a list that is used as a key, then the dictionary will break. General Tip: Do not use mutable objects as keys for dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks all, I have changed the code as per your suggestion and it works now. Although I am not sure if I can get rid of the string in the comparer. It works now

Comment: @user1131926 Then post an answer showing how you fixed it. Don't edit your question. Now you have a question with working code asking "Why does this code not work".

Comment: @Scott. I will post it as  the answer. thx again

Answer (score 0):

Posting the changed code

```
    var dict = new Dictionary<List<MyKey>, Emp>(new MyCustomComparer());

    var key1 = new List<MyKey>
                   {
                       {new MyKey{ Name = "string1"}}
                   };

    dict.Add(key1, new Emp());
    var key2 = new List<MyKey>
                   {
                       {new MyKey{ Name = "string1"}}
                   };


    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key2))
    {
        dict.Add(key2, new Emp());
    }


public class MyKey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var myKey = obj as MyKey;
        if (myKey != null)
        {
            return Name == myKey.Name;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Emp
{
}
```

comparer class

```
public class MyCustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<MyKey>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<MyKey> x, IEnumerable<MyKey> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<MyKey> obj)
    {
        return string.Join(",", obj.Select(s => s.Name)).GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Comment: While this does solve your immediate problem you are going to run in to issues if you modify the list after you add it to the dictionary. To see this in action make `key1` a empty list then call `dict.Add(key1, new Emp());` after that do `key1.Add(new MyKey{ Name = "string1"})` then run the rest of your program unmodified.

Comment: Your comparer can be easily broken if any of the names have commas in them.  You shouldn't be concatting the strings together, but rather combining the hashes of each of the strings.

Comment: @Servy I agree that he should not be combining strings but a comma in the name would not break it. In fact he could just as easly do `string.Join("", obj.Select(s => s.Name))` the string is never "looked at" it is only used as a opaque blob for generating the hash code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain In this case his `Equals` check is done properly, so yes, it would only increase his collision rate, rather than cause incorrect behavior.  I'm used to seeing people use the same pattern in both places, resulting in possible false positives.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain what will be your suggestion ?

Comment: Well because your keys are really just the string of names change your dictionary to be `Dictionary<string, Emp>` and just use `string.Join(",", key1.Select(s => s.Name))` as the key. You could get some false positives for example the list `{"a,b", "c"}` and the list `{"a", "b", "c"}` would be equal but you could get around that by using a non printable character as your separator. Any character would work (except maybe `\0`), I recommend the character "Record Separator" (hex value `1E`) so your join would be `string.Join("\x1E", key1.Select(s => s.Name))`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
    public class MyCustomKey : ReadOnlyCollection<MyKey>
    {
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Aggregate(0, (c, i) => c + i.Name.GetHashCode()*i.Name.Length);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var myKey = obj as MyCustomKey;
            if (myKey!= null && myKey.Count == this.Count)
            {
                return myKey.Zip(this, (i, j) => i.Name == j.Name).All(i=>i);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    var dict = new Dictionary<MyCustomKey, Emp>();

    var key1 = new MyCustomKey(new[] {new MyKey {Name = "string1"}});
    dict.Add(key1, new Emp());
    var key2 = new MyCustomKey(new[] {new MyKey {Name = "string1"}});

    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key2))
    {
         dict.Add(key2, new Emp());
    }
```

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Actually the accepted answer for that question says this is the perfect time to inherit from list. All the poster is doing is extending the behavior of List to support generating the hash code and equals to use the members in the list. The list still only represents a list, it just modifies equality behavior.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'd argue that a key must/should be immutable, and since List isn't, the class doesn't actually represent a list. ReadOnlyCollection I'd buy.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer to make the immutable key